# PyQGIS 3: Pie Charts not rendering, Autogenerate pie SetUpperValue size from expression attributes

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have used code from previous post to create pie charts. I manage to display the pie graphs after going into properties and setting find to Maximum Value. Though this is not happening automatically when rendering with my code.

[image]

The uppervalue must also be calculated from the maximum value from all my attributes that is passed in as an expression.

Lastly, is there also a way to autogenerate the colors for each field?
I don't want to manually add the code for each variable each time I run this script since these fields might change in the future.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)


pointFile = ".../Site Location.shp"



Layer = QgsVectorLayer(pointFile, 'Site Location', 'ogr')


    
diagram = QgsPieDiagram()

ds = QgsDiagramSettings()

dColors = {'Field1': QColor('#ff0000'),
                    'Field2': QColor('#00ff00'),
                    'Field3': QColor('#0000ff'),
                    'Field4': QColor('#d2b4de')}


ds.categoryColors = dColors.values()
ds.categoryAttributes = dColors.keys()
ds.categoryLabels = ds.categoryAttributes

dr = QgsLinearlyInterpolatedDiagramRenderer()
dr.setLowerValue(0.0)
dr.setLowerSize(QSizeF(0.0,0.0))
dr.setUpperValue(46)  # Here you should set the maximum value of both attributes
dr.setUpperSize(QSizeF(10, 10))
strExp = ' "Field1"  +  "Field2"+ "Field3" + "Field4"'
dr.setClassificationField(strExp)

dr.setDiagram(diagram)

dr.setDiagramSettings(ds)
Layer.setDiagramRenderer(dr)

# Set diagram layer settings:
dls = QgsDiagramLayerSettings()
dls.dist = 0
dls.priority = 0
dls.xPosColumn = -1
dls.yPosColumn = -1
dls.placement = 0

Layer.setDiagramLayerSettings(dls)

label_settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
Layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(label_settings))
Layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
Layer.triggerRepaint()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(Layer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

Look at the following methods as I'm not sure you should use `setClassificationField` (PS: not certain as only supposed from the API doc)

```py
dr.setClassificationAttributeExpression(strExp)
dr.setClassificationAttributeIsExpression(True)
```

The part that calculate the value for the "Find" button should be the following. It's a port of the C++ code e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/gui/vector/qgsdiagramproperties.cpp#L704

```py
maxValue = 0.0;
exp = QgsExpression(strExp)
context = QgsExpressionContext()

context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope())
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(QgsProject.instance()))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.mapSettingsScope(iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings()))
context.appendScope(QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(Layer))

exp.prepare(context)
if (not exp.hasEvalError()):
    feature = QgsFeature()
    features = Layer.getFeatures()
    while features.nextFeature(feature):
        context.setFeature(feature);
        maxValue = max(maxValue, float(exp.evaluate(context)));
# Use the maxValue to set the upper value
dr.setUpperValue(maxValue)
```

Comment: Hi thanks this code solved my problem. Thanks!!! I originally saw the setClassificationAttributeExpression and setClassificationAttributeIsExpression methods, I didn't realize they need to be used together. I struggle with understanding the documentation sometimes. I guess I'll get better in time. Thanks a lot!